# Spring boot API - How to scale an App as users grow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scale

I am making an API with Spring boot which will maybe have requests peaks.

So let's get into the worst scenario. Imagine that suddenly I have 2 million API requests.

***What can I do to be able to handle this?***

I read something about queues and workers but I don't know if that's the best way.

***Is there some way to do it with something with AWS?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always a tricky question to answer. Firstly does your app *really need* to scale to 2 million API requests at peak? I ask because it is easy to over-engineer a solution 'to deal with future scale' which ends up a bit buggy and not even dealing with current scale very well as a result.

But assuming you really will have massive request peaks, the current microservice approach (or buzzword?) is quite a popular way of dealing with these periods of high demand. Basically you split your application up into smaller, self contained services ('*microservices*') which can be more-easily scaled as required.

Individual microservices can then be scaled up and down to match the load, using something like [Kubernetes](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/kubernetes/scaling-microservices-with-kubernetes/) or [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

In terms of where Spring ties into this, Spring has a handy set of technologies called [Spring Cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) - you'll notice Spring Cloud AWS there, too (although Spring Cloud in general can also work fine on bare metal servers, Docker, Kubernetes etc etc). A year ago I put together a simple [Spring cloud/microservices demo](https://github.com/TristanPerry/java8-spring-cloud-microservice-demo) on Github which shows how different Spring-powered microservices can fit together, which you may find useful.

The other nice thing with microservices is that you can swap out the language that a particular service is written in fairly easily, especially if the microservices 'speak' to each-other in a general format (such as JSON via REST requests). So if you had 10 different microservices, all powered by Spring Boot, but you find that a couple of them are better written in another language, you can just rewrite them: as long as they send and receive data in the same way, then the other parts of your system don't need to care.

Okay, that's a lot of buzzwords and new concepts. Feel free to ask questions if I can clarify anything, but microservices + kubernetes/AWS is a popular solution.

Other approaches which will probably work equally well, however, are:

1. **Serverless** - this is where you use a bunch of cloud-provider's tools and solutions to power your webapp, including things like lambdas, instead of hosting your application on a traditional server/VM. [This medium tutorial](https://medium.com/@drwtech/learn-aws-serverless-by-creating-a-basic-email-signup-list-2b5ce5c94a19) gives a simple introduction to serverless.
2. **Monoliths** - this is a traditional web application which is a single, large, sprawling codebase, but this doesn't mean you can only have one instance of it running (i.e. you can still scale it). This very site [is a successfully scalable](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/06/scaling-stack-overflow) monolith.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, as there are lots of different solutions:

1) Use a **load balancer** and have multiple instances of your application

2) Use a **containerization tool like docker and kubernetes** to increase the amount of instances depending on current load. You can essentially scale on demand

3) We don't know what your app actually does: is it read heavy, is it write heavy? Will users be downloading content? The answers to this question can change whether or not a specific solution is feasible

4) You can maybe use a messenger queue like RabbitMQ to assist with distributing load across different services. You can have multiple services reading from this queue and performing actions at the same time...but again, this depends on what your app will actually be doing.

Check out AWS *EC2* and *Elastic Beanstalk*. You can also get a simple load balancer up and running with nginx. Good luck